# Determining if count = 0 for each element in a tuple in a specific file - flagging that element if 0

Tags: python, pandas, count, tuples

I am trying to determine if it is possible to have a tuple with some key phrases and have a seperate count for each element within that tuple. For example:

```
Example Tuple = (('Foo', 'Bar', 'Help', 'Me')
Element1_count = 0
for line in file
    Element1_count = line.count(Element1)
    if Element1_count == 1:
        Element1_count = Element1_count + 1
if Element1 == 0:
    print ('Warning %s not present'%Element1)

#iterate through each tuple element
```

The tuple will be automatically generated by some phrases I am looking for, which can vary.

Any alternatives are very much welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `Categorical` + `value_counts`, if that is zero , it will show in result , as 0

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ele':['Foo','Help']})
elelist=('Foo', 'Bar', 'Help', 'Me')
df=df[df.ele.isin(elelist)].copy()
df.ele=pd.Categorical(df.ele,elelist)
df.ele.value_counts()
Out[635]: 
Help    1
Foo     1
Me      0
Bar     0
Name: ele, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'elements': ['Foo', 'Bar']})
elements=('Foo', 'Bar', 'Help', 'Me')
count_df = {}
for ele in elements:
    if ele in count:
            count_df[ele] = count[ele]
    else:
            count_df[ele] = 0

print(count_df)
{'Foo': 1, 'Bar': 1, 'Help': 0, 'Me': 0}
```